# Sql joins returning Null Results and not accepting conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables that I am trying to get data from yet my join statement returns `null`. I have tried `full, left and right joins` with no success. Below I have provided my code and the diagram, the table that returns `null` values is the `ChannelData` table. I am trying to sum the `Vvalue from this table, when i add the condition that i commented out below i.e.`between start and end date` my query return no results. I know there must be a problem with my joins but I have tried everything. This table is not normalized properly and I have to use it as is:

```
 DECLARE @bp varchar(4)
DECLARE @priority varchar(2)
DECLARE @startDate datetime
DECLARE @endDate datetime

SET @bp = 1710
SET @priority = 2

SET @endDate = (SELECT EndDate FROM BillingPeriod WHERE BillingPeriodClass_ID = 1 AND CODE = @BP)
SET @startDate = (SELECT EndDate FROM BillingPeriod WHERE BillingPeriodClass_ID = 1 AND CODE = @BP -1 )
SET @startDate = dateadd(minute, 1, @startDate)


SELECT  CGS.Description, SUM(CD.Vvalue) AS P_Val, COUNT(CD.VValue) AS P_Rec, DI.Margin
FROM CGS AS CGS

 FULL JOIN ChannelParameter AS CP ON CP.ID = CGS.ID
 FULL JOIN ChannelData AS CD ON CP.ID = CD.ID 
FULL JOIN DataIntegrity AS DI ON DI.CGS_ID_1 = CGS.ID OR DI.CGS_ID_2 = CGS.ID

WHERE --CD.DDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate AND
    DI.Priority = @priority

 group by CGS.Description, DI.Margin
```

[Click this for Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahRY8.png)

Please see below:

[Channel Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWJvJ.png)

[Channel Parameter Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKBnx.png)

I have attached pictures as links: also here is what i mean by the table not being normalised properly they both have CGS.ID as a primrary and foreign key but this is actually a primary key in the cgs table the problem is when i try and join the DI table i dont get results from all tables:

```
DECLARE @bp varchar(4)
DECLARE @priority varchar(2)
DECLARE @startDate datetime
DECLARE @endDate datetime

SET @bp = 1710
SET @priority = 2

SET @endDate = (SELECT EndDate FROM BillingPeriod WHERE BillingPeriodClass_ID = 1 AND CODE = @BP)
SET @startDate = (SELECT EndDate FROM BillingPeriod WHERE BillingPeriodClass_ID = 1 AND CODE = @BP -1 )
SET @startDate = dateadd(minute, 1, @startDate)


SELECT  CGS.Description, SUM(CD.Vvalue) AS P_Val, COUNT(CD.VValue) AS P_Rec
FROM CGS AS CGS

 FULL JOIN ChannelParameter AS CP ON CP.ID = CGS.ID
 FULL JOIN ChannelData AS CD ON CP.ID = CD.ID 


WHERE CD.DDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate and CGS.ID = 88


 group by CGS.Description
```

RESULT :

```
       Description                         P_Val         P_Rec

EP 308 12 CONTROL TRF FEEDER NO 1 - Q Exp,    4514.37,   1488
```

Comment: can you show sample data from all the relevant tables please? the obvious issues is that there are no matching ID between CP and CD... can you show a query which selects from the CP and CD tables where the IDs are the same?

Comment: i have edited my question to show you what i mean

Comment: regardless of what join you use in your query, if you reference the table in the where clause, the effect is the same as an INNER JOIN on the table.. so using an outerjoin on your dataintegrity table is actually an innerjoin since the table is part of the where clause..  do you get results for the following? what does your DI table look like?  Do you get results for the following?

select
cd.ID as cd_id
,cp.ID as cp_id


from [EC6LON].[dbo].[CannelDate] cd

inner join [EC6LON].[dbo].[CannelParameter] cp
 on cp.ID = cd.ID
 
 where cp.ID = 89

Comment: Not sure whether it's actually your problem, but you've declared \@bp and \@priority as varchar and then treated them as numeric types in the query. They're probably being implicitly cast correctly anyway but try declaring them as int just in case? If that doesn't help can you include the parameters in the select clause and show the sample output so we can see that they're being assigned correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pretty clear that there is no matched record for `CD.DDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate` condition. And I suspected that `@startDate` variable might be `null` because of returning no record for `CODE = @BP -1` condition. So, would you try to change this line;

```
SET @startDate = (SELECT top 1 EndDate FROM BillingPeriod 
WHERE BillingPeriodClass_ID = 1 AND CODE < @BP order by CODE desc)
```